# Why UserControl Page_PreInit event does not fire?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In User Control Page Page_preinit Event not firing.
The code given Bellow:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (!Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("abcd/Index.aspx?Auth=Fail");
    }
    else
    {
        FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)Page.User.Identity;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
        String[] userDatas = ticket.UserData.Split('|');
        ViewState["Role"] = userDatas[0];
        ViewState["Language"] = userDatas[2];
        this.Page.Theme = userDatas[1];
    }
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: put your design page side as well

Comment: How is the `AutoEventWireup` attribute set on your user control? On your page?

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. It's not at all obvious that PreInit isn't fired for user controls, especially if you spend most of your time looking at pages instead.

Answer (score 6):

`UserControls` are actually derived from **[`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** class and  doesn't have any `PreInit` event available.

**Inheritance Hierarchy**

```
System.Object
  System.Web.UI.Control
    System.Web.UI.TemplateControl
      System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

`PreInit` event is available for Page Class.